# Filter a stream and put values to a map based on a condition

Tags: java-8, java-stream

I have a string which I need to convert into a map. There are two timestamps in the string so those values need to be stored as timestamp and other values need to be stored as String. Currently I use two maps and then combine the values of those maps into a new map as given below. I would like to know if there is a way to do it using a single map.

```
String paramsValues = reportGenerationSchedules.get(0).getReport_parameters();
            paramsValues = paramsValues.substring(1,paramsValues.length()-1);

            Map<String, Object> reportGenerationParams1 = Arrays.asList(paramsValues.split(",")).stream()
                    .filter(x -> x.toString().split("=")[0].contains("Date"))
                    .collect(Collectors.toMap(x -> x.toString().split("=")[0],
                            x -> Timestamp.valueOf(x.toString().split("=")[1])));

            Map<String, Object> reportGenerationParams2 = Arrays.asList(paramsValues.split(",")).stream()
                    .collect(Collectors.toMap(x -> x.toString().split("=")[0],
                            x -> x.toString().split("=")[1]));

            Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<String,Object>();
            params.putAll(reportGenerationParams2);
            params.putAll(reportGenerationParams1);
```

Comment: Can you show us some sample data for `paramsValues`?

Comment: startDate=2019-02-02 00:00:00.0,Name=20190702-all-active-subs-env-aa597d5d-494a-41dd-84e9-729331ae1c4b,partnerExternalId=SamplePartner_Test2,endDate=2019-03-02 00:00:00.0
Here is a sample

Comment: Your two maps are logically not the same thing.  One maps string keys to `Timestamp` values, and the other just maps strings to other strings.  I'm not sure it even makes good sense to put both these maps into a single map.  Maybe just keep them separate.

Comment: I need to have a single map as that map is going to be used somewhere else. I'm using two maps because when I combine the both, the latter will override the keys which are having string values with timestamp values so that both string and timestamp values will be containing in the same map.

Comment: Then your data model seems to have some problems.  If you want as single map, then you're probably going to be stuck with `Map<String, Object>`.

Comment: Thanks for your input. Appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define a function like this:

```
 Function<String, Object> function = str -> str.contains("Date") ? 
                               Timestamp.valueOf(str.split("=")[1]) : 
                                str.split("=")[1];
```

and use this function:

```
 Map<String, Object> reportGenerationParams1 = Arrays.asList(paramsValues.split(","))
            .stream()
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(x -> x.split("=")[0],x -> function.apply(x)));
```

---

```
Arrays.stream(paramsValues.split(","))
                    .map(x -> x.split("=",2))
                    .collect(Collectors.toMap(ar -> ar[0],
                            ar -> ar[1].contains("Date") ?
                                    Timestamp.valueOf(ar[1]) : ar[1]))
```

Comment: What’s the point of specifying `x -> function.apply(x)` instead of just `function`? Or why not specifying the actual function right where needed, instead of declaring that superfluous variable? And you can use `Arrays.stream(paramsValues.split(","))` instead of going the `List` detour. In contrast, repeating `x.split("=")` in both functions, instead of doing it once in a preceding `map` step, is a discouraged simplification.

Comment: @Holger, thanks for your comment. i thought maybe it would be more readable thats why i declared a variabe. x-function.apply (x) was my fault. and honesty i thought about 'Arrays.stream ()' and also you are right not to need to repeat 'x.split ()'.